# Cannot edit location of points in Feature Layer in ArcGIS Online after using Collector

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, feature-layer, arcgis-collector

I have students in my GIS class who have created feature layers in ArcGIS Pro to collect points on our campus using Collector on a cell phone.  After going out to collect points they return to the classroom to edit those points.

While they are able to update attributes on ArcGIS Online they are unable to relocate any points without them reverting back to the original location.

Is there something we can do in either building the feature layer or adjusting its settings once it is published that could alleviate this issue?

Comment: Does your feature have z values on the layer http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014234

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may be an issue of edit privileges of the user.

[Edit features](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/edit-features.htm) provides an overview of editing features in ArcGIS Online(AGOL).

> Some maps include feature layers that can be edited by anyone viewing the map. These editable layers are useful when the map author wants community input. For example, an author might include an editable feature layer that allows the birding community to post their bird sightings directly on the map and attach media files, such as photographs, audio files, and video files, to the specific observation points. Because these features are part of the layer, any changes made on the map are immediately viewable to everybody who has access to the layer, even when the layer is part of a different map. Authors can enable editing on ArcGIS Server feature service layers and hosted feature layers.

You should have full control and privileges to provide access for your students.

> The owner of an editable features layer decides whether to allow editing and sets an editing level. Editing levels determine if you can add features only, update feature attributes only, or add, update, and delete features. If the feature layer is editable and you have privileges to edit features, you will see the Edit button at the top of Map Viewer. Edits are automatically saved to the layer.

You could learn more about privileges available to assign to users:

[Levels, roles, and privileges](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm)

> Organizations can use, create, and share a wide range of geographic content, including maps, scenes, apps, layers, and analytics. The ability of individual organization members to access and work with content in different ways depends on the privileges they have in the organization. Levels allow organizations to control the scope of privileges that can be assigned to members through roles.

Comment: When these particular layers were published they were set to "editable" in ArcGIS Pro in order to allow for edits by others.  In the settings of these layers it does show that "Enable editing" is checked.  In addition, I did not create any of these layers and I am not the owner.  When the students access their web map containing these layer they are only able to edit attributes not the location of the feature.  Is there another place I should be looking to change settings?

Comment: If you have access to administration rights on AGOL, I would check there as well.